# explore_lite targets places that cannot be moved

Tags: navigation, slam, ros-noetic, teb-local-planner

https://youtu.be/2WH144VZezA

As shown in the video, explore_lite targets a place that cannot be moved, and teb_local_planner stops moving.

I want to aim far away from walls and avoiding obstacle areas.

This is my explore_lite parameter.

```
  <node pkg="explore_lite" type="explore" name="explore">
    <remap from="costmap" to="map"/>

    <param name="robot_base_frame" value="base_link"/>
    <param name="costmap_topic" value="map"/>
    <param name="costmap_updates_topic" value="map_updates"/>
    <param name="visualize" value="true"/>

    <param name="planner_frequency" value="0.5"/>
    <param name="progress_timeout" value="60.0"/>
    <param name="potential_scale" value="0.001"/>
    <param name="orientation_scale" value="0.0"/>
    <param name="gain_scale" value="1.0"/>
    <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.3"/>
    <param name="min_frontier_size" value="0.5"/>
  </node>
```